# f.position.vsub is not a function Cannon.js

Tags: javascript, cannon.js

I keep getting `f.position.vsub is not a function` whenever I create a cannon.js body. My code is as follows:

```
var boxShape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(1, 1, 1));
var examplecannonbody = new CANNON.Body({
    mass: 0,
    shape: boxShape
});
```

I am using the minified version from GitHub.

Comment: Can you post the script tag where you are loading Cannon? Also try using not the minified JS.

Comment: What version should I use?

Comment: Any version would work, but the latest is v0.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was because I was sending the body to a webworker and all functions get stripped off when sent to a webworker.